# Kusto query for dynamic json

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have json like below:

[image]

How to read data like below in Azure log analytics using Kusto query

```
Count
1234
566
45
76
970
```

I have tried bag_unpack but I am getting data in multiple column while I want this in one column

Comment: Provide your table structure, and how does your input table look like

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results:

**`KQL query which worked for me:`**

```
let rith = datatable (Col1: string)
[
  "{source:{count:1234}}",
"{source1:{count:566}}",
"{sink:{count:45}}",
"{destination:{count:76}}",
"{abc:{count:970}}"
];
let newrith=rith
|extend x= split(Col1,':')
|extend y=split(x[2],'}')
|project Count=toint(y[0]);
newrith
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0WOywqDMBBF94H8w%20BGBRdqtVJLVn6GuPAR2rQhER2pYv33qm0sA7M4h8u9kiN0Au/AoClxvUpycDItgxR67IS6uZTklABYc6%20HrubpXOtBYRqEp2hZLI8SYwKj4vP5MEI9DY5iQxveo1AlCq2MTI5IWdUGXhJ/pZQUV0rkulTx1zaWbY%20SNx%20RqwZGBn0rBe6zPTu13b%20b2FeNeVh49rKrttMPXiNkWwdDLRQ6U%204X7trya/gA5P4IOBcBAAA=)

**`Note:`**

If your input is JSON change to string using `tostring()` in first split as split(tostring(Col1),':')

Comment: Thanks Rithvik for answering.